# How can I compile certain files and add flags in a Makefile only when a specific target is selected?

Tags: c, makefile, compilation, cflags, ldflags

I am currently facing a problem when writing a Makefile for a C project.

In particular, my project should have at least two Makefile targets (`target_light` and `target_full`), being `target_light` the default one.

`target_light` should compile all my source files, except few ones which require the installation of an external library on the system (which are saved in `src/extra`, for .c files, and `include/extra`, for .h files).
`target_full` should instead compile all the files, including the ones which need the external library. It should also add some flags to `CFLAGS` and `LDLIBS`.

I currently have a Makefile similar to the following one:

```
EXECNAME=MyExecutable

CC=gcc

SRC_DIR=src
OBJ_DIR=obj

SRC_DIR_EXTERNAL_FILES=src/extra
OBJ_DIR_EXTERNAL_FILES=obj/extra

SRC=$(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)
OBJ=$(SRC:$(SRC_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)

SRC_EXTERNAL_FILES=$(wildcard $(SRC_DIR_EXTERNAL_FILES)/*.c)
OBJ_EXTERNAL_FILES=$(SRC_EXTERNAL_FILES:$(SRC_DIR_EXTERNAL_FILES)/%.c=$(OBJ_DIR_EXTERNAL_FILES)/%.o)

CFLAGS += -Wall -O2 -Iinclude
LDLIBS += -lpthread -lm

.PHONY: all clean

all: target_light

target_light: CC=gcc
target_light_embedded: CC=x86_64-openwrt-linux-musl-gcc

target_light_debug: CFLAGS += -g
target_light_debug: target_light

target_light target_light_debug target_light_embedded: $(EXECNAME)

$(EXECNAME): $(OBJ_CC)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJ_DIR)/*.o $(OBJ_DIR_EXTERNAL_FILES)/*.o
    $(RM) $(EXECNAME)
    -rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)
```

I'm currently struggling to find a way to add `target_full` to this Makefile, which should also take into account `SRC_DIR_EXTERNAL_FILES` `OBJ_DIR_EXTERNAL_FILES` `SRC_EXTERNAL_FILES` `OBJ_EXTERNAL_FILES`, in order to compile the additional files only when requested.

How can I perform this operation? Is there a good way to do so within the Makefile?

My second question is: how can I add, at the same time, flags to both `CFLAGS` and `LDLIBS` only when `target_full` is selected?
I tried writing:

```
target_full: CFLAGS += -DENABLE_CODE_EXTERNAL_LIB -Iinclude/extra
    LDLIBS += -lext_lib
```

And then changing the `$(EXECNAME)` line in:

```
target_light target_light_debug target_light_embedded target_full: $(EXECNAME)
```

But the additional `LDLIBS` flag seems to be always considered, even when `target_light` is selected.

Should I do something like the following lines, repeating two times `target_full`?

```
target_full: CFLAGS += -DENABLE_CODE_EXTERNAL_LIB -Iinclude/extra
target_full: LDLIBS += -lext_lib
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Yep, you need an extra line for each target-specific variable, as in your last example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `target_light` and `target_full` share object files, then when you build `target_light` it compiles the sources without `target_full` `CFLAGS`. When you then build `target_full` it won't rebuild the existing object files with extra `CFLAGS`.

Possible solutions:

1. Build all object files with `target_full` `CFLAGS`. This way the object files can be shared between the targets.
2. Build object files for `target_light` and `target_full` with different `CFLAGS` into different directories. In this case the object files aren't shared between the targets.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In the end I decided to implement the second solution you suggested me, as my aim was to have a Makefile which can be used to compile my project with `target_light` even when no external library is actually installed.